# Strtok() Segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtok

```
struct args
{
    char command[64];
    char args[2][64];
};

int argscount = 0;
struct args* arguments;
int buffersize = 64;
char *ptoken = NULL;
char input[buffersize];
char *pstr = NULL;



int a = read(0,input,buffersize);
pstr = input;
arguments = malloc(sizeof(struct args));        
if(a>0){  
    ptoken = strtok(&pstr," ");
    strcpy(arguments->command,ptoken);
    printf("TOKEN:%s\n", ptoken);
    while( ptoken != NULL ) {
        if(argscount > 1){break;}
        ptoken = strtok(NULL, ' ');
        strcpy(arguments->args[argscount],ptoken);
        argscount++;  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is most likely to be at

```
ptoken = strtok(&pstr," ");
```

First argument to strtok should be

```
char *
```

You have it as

```
char **
```

Comment: Good catch! I thought `strtok` did take `char **` and returned the new pointer to start from. I should have double checked.

Comment: OK that works for the first try. But for those in while loop its still not working. Is ptoken = strtok(NULL, ' ') looks rihgt?

Comment: Don't ignore warnings - no wonder you get errors if you do that. `" "` is a string, but `' '` is a single `char`. Pay attention to your compiler. Turn your warning level up, and fix them all.

Comment: Hi folks I modified my code but seems strtok() didn't work. It didn't split the string by white space.

Comment: The line "ptoken = strtok(NULL, ' ');" should be "ptoken = strtok(ptoken, " ");".  Also, it's a good idea to step through your code using gdb and ensuring that everything is as expected.

Comment: @NobWong: How about posting a real compilable program instead of making everyone guess what you're doing and what you've changed.

Answer (score 2):

`read` does not return a null terminated string, which `strtok` expects. You will need to allocate one extra byte in input to add the `'\0'`. You can look at the return value of `read` to see how many bytes were read and then place the `'\0'` at `input[a]`.

```
int a = read(0,input,buffersize-1);
input[a] = '\0';
```

Comment: Are you seeing your TOKEN: `printf`? Can you step through in a debugger or add a few debug prints to see where the crash is occurring?

Comment: Actually.. after I changed it, it simply become seg fault and didn't print anything.

Comment: I think Arun Taylor has the second piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

Several fixes (and other) in your code.  Comments described what I changed:  (if `read()` function was defined, It might have built)  Also added main, just to compile through errors.

```
#include <ansi_c.h>

 struct args
{
    char command[64];
    char args[2][64];
};

int argscount = 0;
struct args* arguments;
size_t buffersize = 64; //changed to size_t
char *ptoken = NULL;
char input[64];  //variable initializer not allowed, changed
char *pstr = NULL;

int read(int a, char *s, size_t size);


main(void)
{

    int a = read(0,input,buffersize);

pstr = input;
arguments = malloc(sizeof(struct args));        
if(a>0)
    {  
        ptoken = strtok(pstr," "); //changed &pstr to pstr
        strcpy(arguments->command,ptoken);
        printf("TOKEN:%s\n", ptoken);
        while( ptoken != NULL ) {
            if(argscount > 1){break;}
            ptoken = strtok(NULL, " "); //changed ' ' to " "
            strcpy(arguments->args[argscount],ptoken);
            argscount++;  
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a normal, sensible way of doing it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct args {
    char command[64];
    char args[2][64];
};

int main(void) {
    char input[64] = {0};

    if ( read(0, input, sizeof(input) - 1) == -1 ) {
        perror("unsuccessful read() operation");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char * ptoken = strtok(input, " ");
    if ( ptoken == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No valid input\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    struct args arguments;
    strcpy(arguments.command, ptoken);
    printf("COMMAND: %s\n", arguments.command);

    int argscount = 0;
    while ( ptoken && argscount < 2 ) {
        ptoken = strtok(NULL, " ");
        if ( ptoken ) {
            strcpy(arguments.args[argscount], ptoken);
            printf("TOKEN: %s\n", arguments.args[argscount++]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ ./args
test
COMMAND: test

paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ ./args
test this
COMMAND: test
TOKEN: this

paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ ./args
test this one
COMMAND: test
TOKEN: this
TOKEN: one

paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ ./args
test this one two
COMMAND: test
TOKEN: this
TOKEN: one
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$
```

I'll leave stripping the newline as an exercise for you.